# mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied for GRU

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gated-recurrent-unit

I am creating a GRU to do some classification for a project, and I'm relatively new to Pytorch and implementing GRUs. I know similar questions like this one have been answered already but I can't seem to bring the same solution over to my own problem. I understand that there is an issue with the shape/order of my fc arrays but after trying to change things I can no longer see the trees for the wood. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Below I have attached my code and the error. The datasets im using contain 24 features with a label in the 25th column.

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision  # torch package for vision related things
import torch.nn.functional as F  # Parameterless functions, like (some) activation functions
import torchvision.datasets as datasets  # Standard datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms  # Transformations we can perform on our dataset for augmentation
from torch import optim  # For optimizers like SGD, Adam, etc.
from torch import nn  # All neural network modules
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader  # Gives easier dataset managment by creating mini batches etc.
from tqdm import tqdm  # For a nice progress bar
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Set device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Hyperparameters
input_size = 24
hidden_size = 128
num_layers = 1
num_classes = 2
sequence_length = 1
learning_rate = 0.005
batch_size = 8
num_epochs = 3

# Recurrent neural network with GRU (many-to-one)
class RNN_GRU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(RNN_GRU, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size * sequence_length, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Set initial hidden and cell states
        x = x.unsqueeze(0)
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)

        # Forward propagate LSTM
        out, _ = self.gru(x, h0)
        out = out.reshape(out.shape[0], -1)

        # Decode the hidden state of the last time step
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

class MyDataset(Dataset):
 
  def __init__(self,file_name):
    stats_df=pd.read_csv(file_name)
 
    x=stats_df.iloc[:,0:24].values
    y=stats_df.iloc[:,24].values
 
    self.x_train=torch.tensor(x,dtype=torch.float32)
    self.y_train=torch.tensor(y,dtype=torch.float32)
 
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.y_train)
   
  def __getitem__(self,idx):
    return self.x_train[idx],self.y_train[idx]

nomDs=MyDataset("nomStats.csv")
atkDs=MyDataset("atkStats.csv")
train_loader=DataLoader(dataset=nomDs,batch_size=batch_size)
test_loader=DataLoader(dataset=atkDs,batch_size=batch_size)

# Initialize network (try out just using simple RNN, or GRU, and then compare with LSTM)
model = RNN_GRU(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes).to(device)

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Train Network
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader)):
        # Get data to cuda if possible
        data = data.to(device=device).squeeze(1)
        targets = targets.to(device=device)

        # forward
        scores = model(data)
        loss = criterion(scores, targets)

        # backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        # gradient descent update step/adam step
        optimizer.step()

# Check accuracy on training & test to see how good our model
def check_accuracy(loader, model):
    num_correct = 0
    num_samples = 0

    # Set model to eval
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for x, y in loader:
            x = x.to(device=device).squeeze(1)
            y = y.to(device=device)

            scores = model(x)
            _, predictions = scores.max(1)
            num_correct += (predictions == y).sum()
            num_samples += predictions.size(0)

    # Toggle model back to train
    model.train()
    return num_correct / num_samples


print(f"Accuracy on training set: {check_accuracy(train_loader, model)*100:2f}")
print(f"Accuracy on test set: {check_accuracy(test_loader, model)*100:.2f}")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TESTGRU.py", line 87, in <module>
    scores = model(data)
  File "C:\Users\steph\anaconda3\envs\FYP\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "TESTGRU.py", line 47, in forward
    out = self.fc(out)
  File "C:\Users\steph\anaconda3\envs\FYP\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\steph\anaconda3\envs\FYP\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 94, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "C:\Users\steph\anaconda3\envs\FYP\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1753, in linear
    return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x1024 and 128x2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like these lines

```
        # Forward propagate LSTM
        out, _ = self.gru(x, h0)
        out = out.reshape(out.shape[0], -1)
```

are the problem.

It appears that you only want to feed the hidden state of the last time step.

This could be read from the output in two ways:

1. If you want the output of all layers at the last time step, you should use the second return value of `out, _ = self.gru(x, h0)` not the first.
2. If you want to use just the last layer's output at the last time    step (which seems to be the case), you should use
   `out[:, -1, :]`. With this change, you may not need the
   reshape operation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I wish to have just the last layers output at the last time step. I replaced the second line as you said and now the two lines you referenced look as follows, ```out, _ = self.gru(x, h0), out = out[:, -1, :]``` . However, I am now receiving an error regarding the following line ```loss = criterion(scores, targets)``` that says ```ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (8)```?

Comment: Can you check the output shapes? 

Both after `self.gru` and tensor slicing operations?

Comment: After the self.gru line the shape is [1, 8, 128] and after the following slicing line, it is [1, 128]. Assuming a sequence length of 1, batch size of 8, and a hidden layer of 128. should the batch size and the sequence be in each other's position in the array?

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. You have passed `batch_first=True`, so batch dimension should be first but in the output, it shows at the second position? It could be that the input was provided incorrectly. Can you see the shape of input (x) after the squeeze operation?

Comment: After the x.unsqueeze line, the shape of x is [1, 8, 24] and after the following h0 line, the shape of h0 is [1, 1, 128].

Comment: And the shape of x prior to the unsqueeze line is [8, 24]

Comment: The dimension of input has to be [B, L, H], since batch first is true. But it seems you have a batch size of 8? So you should be doing `.unsqueeze(1)` to insert a dimension for sequence length.

Comment: Yes, that has fixed the issue I believe, it is now in the form [B, L, H], Thank you very much!